# Php increment(++) not working for mysql values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to count the number of downloads for each post in my website.
I am using the following code:

```
$sq2 = mysqli_query($con,"Select * From games where name2='$name'");
$x = mysqli_fetch_array($sq2);
$f = $x['downloads'] ;
$d = $f++;
$sq3 = mysqli_query($con,"Update games set downloads='$d' where name2='$name'");
```

The data type of the column downloads is int but still it isn't working
And thanks in Advance

Comment: Why don't you just use `UPDATE games SET downloads=downloads+1 WHERE ...`?

Comment: `$f++` is a **post-increment**. That is it yields the *current `$f` value* to the assignment expression, and only increments `$f` thereafter.

Comment: @mario is correct. You can use the pre-increment version (as seen in my answer) by replacing the `$f++` with a `++$f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$foo++` operator is the PHP post-increment operator. modifies the original variable, and returns the original value of that variable. You probably want to use the PHP pre-increment operator. ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)) For example:

```
$bar = 1;
$bar++;
$bar++;
```

This returns `$bar` as the value `3`. The post-increment operator returns the original variable before incrementing, so your `$d` value is still the original, unchanged value of `$f`. You can **simplify** your code to work like this:

```
$sq2 = mysqli_query($con,"Select * From games where name2='$name'");
$x = mysqli_fetch_array($sq2);
$f = $x['downloads'] ;
$f++;
$sq3 = mysqli_query($con,"Update games set downloads='$f' where name2='$name'");
```

If you wanted to use the variable `$d` anyways, you could alternatively modify your code to work like this **using the pre-increment operator**:

```
$sq2 = mysqli_query($con,"Select * From games where name2='$name'");
$x = mysqli_fetch_array($sq2);
$f = $x['downloads'] ;
$d = ++$f;
$sq3 = mysqli_query($con,"Update games set downloads='$f' where name2='$name'");
```

Or, just **ignoring the `++` incrementing** operator, you can use this:

```
$sq2 = mysqli_query($con,"Select * From games where name2='$name'");
$x = mysqli_fetch_array($sq2);
$f = $x['downloads'] ;
$d = $f + 1;
$sq3 = mysqli_query($con,"Update games set downloads='$d' where name2='$name'");
```

Comment: @user3764953 If you found this answer helpful, please mark it as accepted, so the question can be closed.